# delete line that contains a case insensitive match

Tags: sed, awk, grep, case-sensitivity

I have a file that contains information as so:

```
20    BaDDOg
31    baddog
42    badCAT
43    goodDoG
44    GOODcAT
```

and I want to delete all lines that contain the word `dog`. This is my desired output:

```
42    badCAT
44    GOODcAT
```

However, the case of `dog` is insensitive.

I thought I could use a sed command: `sed -e "/dog/id" file.txt` , but I can't seem to get this to work. Does it have something to do with me working on an OSX? Is there any other method I could use?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try `grep`:

```
grep -iv dog inputfile
```

`-i` to ignore case and `-v` to invert the matches.

If you want to use `sed` you can do:

```
sed '/[dD][oO][gG]/d' inputfile
```

GNU `sed` extends [pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regexp-Addresses.html) with the `I` modifier, which should make the match case insensitive but this does not work in all flavors of `sed`. For me, this works:

```
sed '/dog/Id' inputfile
```

but it won't work on OS X.

Comment: Perfect. The grep solution was what I was looking for. My version of `sed` is picky.

Answer (score 1):

The `sed` version of OSX is not GNU compliant; it totally miss the `i` flag as you can see in the man page:

```
The value of flags in the substitute function is zero or more of the following:
   N       Make the substitution only for the N'th occurrence of the regular expression in
           the pattern space.
   g       Make the substitution for all non-overlapping matches of the regular expression,
           not just the first one.
   p       Write the pattern space to standard output if a replacement was made.  If the
           replacement string is identical to that which it replaces, it is still considered
           to have been a replacement.
   w file  Append the pattern space to file if a replacement was made.  If the replacement
           string is identical to that which it replaces, it is still considered to have
           been a replacement.
```

You could install `gsed` using [brew](http://brew.sh/index_it.html) with the command

```
brew install gnu-sed
```

and then you can use sed with the case-insensitive flag like this:

```
gsed '/dog/Id' inputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Since OSX appears to have ed, based on https://ss64.com/osx/, you could ask it to delete any lines that match "dog". Unfortunately, you have to do the case-sensitivity yourself:

```
ed -s file.txt <<< $'1,$g/[dD][oO][gG]/d\nw\nq'
```

The command is given in a here-string, and breaks down to this sequence:

- in the address range `1,$` (the whole file)
- `g` -- globally apply the subsequent command against lines that match the upcoming regular expression
- `/[dD][oO][gG]/` -- match "dog", case-insensitively
- `d` -- the command to apply is "delete"
- `w` -- write the updated file to disk
- `q` -- quit ed